# How to pass data to <Link to=""/> in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React and I am trying to recieve data from a server, place it into a table while giving the title of each row a link to send it to its own project.
Using a hashmap I have been able to fetch all the data and place it into a table but I am struggling to give them their own unique link and send them to their own page.
Is there any way I can dynamically give every data row their own unique **Link to...** id and be able to send them to their respective unique pages?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router";
import Practice from "./Practice";

function Projects(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory();
  const { title } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/getproject")
      .then(res => setData(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log("projectconsole"));
  }, []);

  const createTable = () => {
    return data.map(project => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <TableRow key={project.projectid}>
            <TableCell>{project.jobtype}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <Link to="/projects/practice/">{project.title}</Link>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>{new Date(project.deadline).toDateString()}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/projects/practice/:name"
                component={Practice}
              />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <Grid container justify="center">
      <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
        <Typography
          variant="h3"
          style={{
            textAlign: "center",
            marginBottom: "20px",
            color: "#756F6E"
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Projects{" "}
        </Typography>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Job type</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Deadline</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>{createTable()}</TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

[Working code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g679U.png)

Comment: `<Link to={\`/projects/practice/${whatever}\`}>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
<Link to=`/projects/practice/${project.url}`>{project.title}</Link>
```

Comment: I do not have a project.url set up in the database, is it possible for me to assign a pathname to each project.title?